# Higher derivatives of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $$p_n(x)e^{-x^2}$$ be the $n$th derivative of $$e^{-x^2}.$$
Find a formula for $p_n(x)$. We have $p_1(x)=-2x, p_2(x)=4x^2-2$, etc. But what is the general formula for $p_n$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/improve-my-proof-about-this-c-infty-function/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "general formula."  These are (up to some normalization) the [Hermite polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).  They satisfy a nice recurrence and have a nice generating function.  You could torture some kind of general formula out of the generating function but I really don't see the point.

Comment: There's the [Rodrigues formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.01.07.0003.01) among other things... ;)

Comment: @J.M. Rodrigues formula? I clicked on your link and I didn't find it.

Comment: @TCL: *That* is the Rodrigues formula for the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: @J. M.: That was a cruel joke. :)

Answer (score 0):

$p_n$ satisfies the recurrence, $p_{n+1}(x) = p_n'(x) - 2xp_n(x)$ with $p_0(x) = 1$.  <s>This looks to me like it might give you some Tchebyshev polynomial. Something like $p_n(x) = 2 (-1)^n T_n(x)$</s> .

**EDIT:**
I was wrong with the Tchebyshev polynomial thing. Sorry.